# Android Business card scanner library for SDK environment

Tags: android, scanning

Is there any library for business card scanner.I am new to android. Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

**Tools Information:**

**ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine:(Paid)**

ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine is a powerful software development kit which allows developers of mobile and small footprint applications to integrate highly accurate optical character recognition (OCR) technologies that convert images and photographs into manageable and searchable text. Toolkit supports the most popular mobile platforms and devices - iOS (iPhone) and Android.

[ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/)

**Demo App** in play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abbyy.mobile.bcr&hl=en

**Tesseract OCR Engine (mainly maintained by Google):(Free)**

It's used android tesseract tools and is very easy to use.Android application to extract the text from the image being 
captured by the camera of your Android phone! They are using a fork of Tesseract Android Tools by Robert This called Tess Two. 
They are based on the Tesseract OCR Engine and Leptonica image processing libraries.

**Demo App** in Play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.datumdroid.app

**Library available in GitHub**: https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

**OCR Library configure in Eclipse**: http://www.luigimarino.altervista.org/blog/informatica/13-configureandroidlibrary

**OcrApiService** :
Ocrapiservice.com provides an online and cloud based OCR (Optical Character Recognition) REST API

[OcrApiService](http://ocrapiservice.com/)

**Demo** : https://github.com/smart-mobile-software/ocrapiservice

Answer (score -3):

You have more great sources & sdk for business card scan for mobiles here: http://www.card-reader.com/mobile_scanning_solutions.htm